# Facing Model Validation issue .Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

**Hi, I'm using .Net 6 & visual studio 2022 community.

My Model validations through Data Annotations are working for all HTML tags, i want to use only for some fields..**

**Code:**

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Student Name")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a value for Name field")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
        public string Department{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HTML:
**I'm using Tag helpers to render HTML code.****

```
@model MiddleWareComponents.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student";
}

<form asp-controller="home" asp-action="student" method="post" class="mt-3">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Department" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Department" class="form-control" placeholder="department">
            
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

****When we run the code, all html fields are required necessary to fill up , otherwise these fields are giving error and submit button not going to server. But there is only Name field is Required & mentioned in the model. **
**Please give me a solution, how i can restrict some of the fields required to fill up , & some fields are not required. Thanks****

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove below code from your `.csproj`:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Have a look at [Build the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app)  to know more.

**Update:**

> If it removes, then all required field validation are also hide.

Remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`  doesn't hide all required field validation. Please See my result:

[image]

If you remove  `<span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>` will  hide all required field validation.

[image]

Comment: If it removes, then all required field validation are also hide.

Comment: Hi, Qing Guo, 
I'm was using .Net 6, it, the issues resoled by just adding ? operator to make nullable fields, so by using it, we can use non-required fields.

Comment: @Reest Ok, that is a way.